# Testing Redux Enzyme: Component doesn't re-render after state has changed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a connected component (to Redux store) called DrawerAvatar, that I export for testing purpose (Enzyme + Jest) both the connected and non connected version.

Basically, I want to test that my DrawerAvatar render the user avatar when my Redux state `isAuthenticated` is `true`, and it renders a logo picture when `isAuthenticated` is `false`.

**DrawerAvatar.js**

```
export class DrawerAvatar extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const avatarSrc = this.props.isAuthenticated ?
      'http://user-avatar.png'
    ) : (
      'http://logo.png'
    );

    return (
      <StyledAvatarContainer>
        <StyledAvatar src={avatarSrc} />
      </StyledAvatarContainer>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated
});

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, null)
)(DrawerAvatar);
```

And in my test, I'm using the non-connected DrawerAvatar, and connect it to my **real** Redux store via the `Provider` like this: (initiale state: `isAuthenticated: false`)

**DrawerAvatar.test.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from '../../store';
import connectedDrawerAvatar, { DrawerAvatar } from './DrawerAvatar';

describe('Header > DrawerAvatar: component', () => {
  it('should render logo for the DrawerAvatar if not authenticated, and the user avatar if authenticated', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Provider store={store}><DrawerAvatar /></Provider>);
    console.log(wrapper.dive().debug());
    // Output: 
    // <StyledAvatarContainer>
    //  <StyledAvatar src="https://logo.png" />
    // </StyledAvatarContainer>    
    const StyledAvatarSrc = wrapper.dive().find('StyledAvatar').prop('src');
    expect(StyledAvatarSrc).toBe('https://logo.png'); // assertion passed

    store.dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_WITH_EMAIL_REQUESTED_TEST' });
    // the state has been correctly updated, now isAuthenticated: true

    console.log(wrapper.dive().debug());
    // Output: same as above, whereas it should be: 
    // <StyledAvatarContainer>
    //  <StyledAvatar src="https://user-avatar.png" />
    // </StyledAvatarContainer>    
    expect(StyledAvatarSrc).toBe('https://user-avatar.png'); // assertion failed
  });
});
```

And here is my authReducer:

**authReducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false
};

export default function authReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN_WITH_EMAIL_REQUESTED_TEST':
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

So basically, I have a real action with type of `LOGIN_WITH_EMAIL_REQUESTED` that will call a bunch of Redux-saga with Axios, but for testing purpose, I just added to my real authReducer a `LOGIN_WITH_EMAIL_REQUESTED_TEST` case that will set the state `isAuthenticated` to `true` to avoid Axios calls etc...Not sure if it's a good way to do things though..lol

I've tried in vain to force the component to update with `wrapper.update()`...

I've also looked at redux-mock-store, but it seems like you cannot modify the state and only deals with actions and not the states.

I just start writing my first React test so...thank you !

Comment: I believe you will need to call `wrapper.update()` immediately after calling `store.dispatch` in your test. Does that work?

Comment: Yep I did, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: You also need to pull out the prop you want *after* calling dispatch and then update. So for example just after wrapper.update, add a line like `const StyledAvatarSrcUnauth = wrapper.dive().find('StyledAvatar').prop('src');` and then `expect(StyledAvatarSrcUnauth)` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, I want to test that my DrawerAvatar render the user avatar when my Redux state isAuthenticated is true, and it renders a logo picture when isAuthenticated is false.

I would recommend not connecting the entire connected component and trying to bother with Redux at all. You can achieve your expected result with the following:

```
describe('Header > DrawerAvatar: component', () => {
  it('should render logo for the DrawerAvatar if not authenticated, and the user avatar if authenticated', () => {
    let wrapper = shallow(<DrawerAvatar isAuthenticated={false} />);
    let StyledAvatarSrc = wrapper.find('StyledAvatar').prop('src');
    expect(StyledAvatarSrc).toBe('https://logo.png');
    wrapper = shallow(<DrawerAvatar isAuthenticated={true} />);
    StyledAvatarSrc = wrapper.find('StyledAvatar').prop('src');
    expect(StyledAvatarSrc).toBe('https://user-avatar.png');
  });
});
```

Then, you can write separate tests for each of the pieces involved, for example your `mapStateToProps` function, which is really just a simple function that returns an object based on its input. And another simple test of your `authReducer`, etc

Comment: You're the man !! I just thought about it (since states become props!!) and implemented EXACTLY in the way you describe and was about to update my question, but you were quicker :D ! So it's somehow reassuring that I am in the right direction lol Thank you very much !!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it's working. The other approach also should work, but it is against the philosophy of unit testing and getting into more of an integration test. If you are new to Jest, definitely learn `toMatchSnapshot` when you can. Good luck